# How to add selected attribute in f.select helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have written the f.select helper for this code

```
    <select> 
              <option>abc</option>
              <option>def</option>
              <option selected>ghi</option>
    </select>

    <%= f.select(:xFields, ['abc', 'def', 'ghi]) %>
```

How do i make option 'ghi' selected as default?

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

try this:

```
<%= f.select options_for_select(:xFields, ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'ghi') %>
```

---

the following should work

```
<%= f.select(:xFields, [['ghi'], 'abc', 'def']) %>
```

based on [Rails 3: f.select - options_for_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200213/rails-3-f-select-options-for-select)

Comment: If i want to make 'ghi' option selected on start, i will have to add this as first element in this array always? For e.g.
this is not working
          <%= f.select(:xFields, ['abc', 'def', ['ghi']]) %>

Comment: And when i view source of html it is not making the option 'ghi' selected.

Comment: try `<%= f.select options_for_select(:xFields, ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'ghi') %>`

Comment: Yes, i modified your code a bit to 
<%= f.select(:xFields, options_for_select( ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'ghi')) %>
 and it is working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
         <%= f.select(:xFields, options_for_select( ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'ghi')) %>
```